# Dismiss performed UIViewController within controller that performed segue

Tags: ios, swift, controller, dismiss

I have `UINavigationController` with root `UICalendarViewController`. At some time while app running, inside `UICalendarViewController` I perform segue with `UICalendarEventViewController`. I keep reference to the 'UICalendarViewController' using

```
var calendarViewController: UICalendarViewController!
```

Later at some time I have an access to the `UICalendarViewController`, and then I need to dismiss UICalendarEventViewController. How to do this?

Inside `UICalendarViewController` I created

```
var calendarEventViewController: UICalendarEventViewController?
```

But when I try to dismiss it using:

```
calendarViewController.calendarEventViewController.dismissViewController(true, animated: true)
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you pushing the `UICalendarEventViewController` onto the navigation stack? I.e., are you using a 'push' segue?

Comment: yes, Segue: `Show (e.g. Push)`

Comment: In which case, you should be calling the dismissal from inside your `UICalendarViewController` via [delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html). You don't need the references that you have defined there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes for some reason we do not have the same instance of controller what we expect. In my case I didn't get the same instance of `UICalendarViewController`. But there is a way to do this if as me you use UITabBarController as a main navigation:

```
if let navigationController = viewControllersByIdentifier[PLContainerTabBarItemCalendar] as? UINavigationController {
        navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Then I have a current controller, and I can manage them with visible results.